# how to convert a bit mask prefix into a dotted-decimal notation

Tags: php

The input is 32 (32 bit) which corresponds to 255.255.255.255,

or 16 to 255.255.0.0

how to convert the mask prefix into a dotted-decimal notation with php?

i've tried the following, but it didn't went correct:

```
$max_ip_str1 = substr(0, $input[1]).str_repeat('1', $input[1]);#$input[1] corresponds to mask
$mask = long2ip(bindec($max_ip_str1));
```

Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: Still searching for a proper way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mask = long2ip((1<<32)-(1<<(32-$input)));
```

That is 2^32 - 2^X, where X is the number of bits that should not be zero. Then convert what is left to dotted form.

```
$mask = long2ip(((1<<$input)-1)<<(32-$input));
```

This does the same a different way: create `$input` 1's, and then shifting them over to the "top position".

Comment: that is totally what i was searching for)

Comment: and what if converting from dotted form back to the prefix, i.e vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

If you're value is fix like this.

```
32  = 255.255.255.255
16  = 255.255.255.255
```

Try using just a if statement

```
if($input == "32")
{
  $mask = "255.255.255.255";
}
```

Comment: It would be too huge bite of code if manually fixing 2 values            There must be some way to convert one to another