# The network mask prefix and dotted decimal format transformation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Before I ask this question,
I find a related post here:
[how to convert a bit mask prefix into a dotted-decimal notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567415/how-to-convert-a-bit-mask-prefix-into-a-dotted-decimal-notation)

But its PHP knowledge.

After efforts to it, I can convert the dotted decimal to prefix now:

```
e_mask = lambda mask: sum(bin(int(i)).count('1') \
                                 for i in mask.split('.'))

print(e_mask('255.255.255.0'))  # there print `24`
```

But I don't know how to use the `24` convert to `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: `bin((~((1<<(32-24))-1)) & ((1<<32)-1))` => `'0b11111111111111111111111100000000`

Comment: @Dan. Very neat. I like how Python makes the first part into a negative number to preserve the concept of infinite leading ones. TIL

Comment: @Dan. Do you plan on posting a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanD. pointed out, you can easily convert an bit count into a prefix mask. It is fairly easy to then convert the mask into four individual bytes and then into a string:

```
def bits_to_mask(n):
    if n < 0 or n > 32:
        raise ValueError('Bit count must be between 0 and 32')
    mask = (~((1 << (32 - n)) - 1)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return '.'.join(map(str, ((mask >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF for i in range(3, -1, -1))))
```

[[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/C5Us2I)]